# Outlook 2016 Sync Error and Deleted Folder

Tags: outlook, outlook-2016

I have a user who was having Issues with his Outlook folders not syncing correctly with our mail provider and his phone. I found that he was not set up using the secure ssl connection and changed the authentication to it. Outlook immediately synced and deleted the folders that were not syncing correctly. Where did those folders go and how can I get them back. I did not remember to make a backup before making changes to his account. There is no deleted items folder under outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Does the Deleted folder missing?
If so, close Outlook and run "**Outlook.exe /ResetFolderNames**" to reset the default folder names.